# Sequence of percentages with corresponding video retention periods

Tags: percentages

I couldn't think of a better title so I do apologize if it is misleading, but my question is this:

```
Of all videos coming in daily,
100% is kept for 30 days
90% is kept for 180 days
50% is kept for 365 days
15% is kept for 1,825 days
5% is kept indefinitely
```

I'd like to get it all worked down into a 60/20/15/3/2 kind of breakdown where the percentages work out to 100% rather than 260%. The reason being for this is that I have a pre-built calculator for this kind of stuff, but it requires the percentages to be =100% for it to be accurate. Putting in the percentages provided would have given me completely blown up and useless results, hence the question. If there is a better way to go about figuring this out than that method, then I am open to all suggestions.

### My Figuring:

How much video coming in daily is extraneous, I just need to figure out how much video is actually being retained at each of the retention policy intervals (lets call "indefinitely" 75 years or 27,375 days).

Giving the hours of video coming in daily an arbitrary number of 200, my thinking is that all videos last at least 30 days and then 10% of those are deleted so 180 hours per day is kept for at least 180 days. Then 50% of those videos are deleted at the 180 day mark which comes out to be 100 hours of video per day is kept for at least 365 days. Furthering that idea, 85% of those videos are deleted at the 365 day mark resulting in 30 hours of video per day is kept for at least 1,825 days. Lastly, 95% of those videos are deleted at the 1,825 day mark leaving a whole 10 hours of video per day being kept for at least indefinitely.

Using those numbers [daily intake x (number of days in the policy - previous policy length)], I can figure that there is a breakdown of:

```
6,000 hours of video is all that makes up the 30 days
27,000 hours of video makes up the following 150 days (180-30)
18,500 hours of video makes up the following 185 days (365-180)
43,800 hours of video makes up the following 1,460 days (1,825-365)
255,500 hours of video makes up the following 25,550 days (27,375-1,825)
```

And those work out to be 1.7%, 7.7%, 5.3%, 12.5%, and 72.8% (=100%).

---

Is my method to all this madness the best way to go about it? **Am I even right?** Are there any shortcuts that I could have taken to make this much easier such as find the percentage first and then work the other angles?

### EDIT:

The percentages I am looking for and the percentages I calculated are completely different. I am fairly confident that I calculated the percentages incorrectly based upon incorrect number of hours of video at each step in the retention policy.

I am after the breakdown of videos on any given day, not the % each level makes up of the total retention policy as I have been trying to calculate.

I know my calculator works, I just need the right numbers to plug into it so I'm going to do some more work.

Comment: Why do you want percentage to add up to a 100%? That seems completely arbitrary.

Comment: I should have explained that part a bit, but it comes down to the fact that I have a calculator that does all the work for me, but it requires the percentages to add up to 100% for it to calculate things correctly. If I was given the breakdown in the =100% format, I wouldn't have even had the need to ask the question, but the percentages being what they are threw me way off.

Comment: You need to go in depth as to what you actually want to have calculated, because I have hard time imagining a calculation that requires such bizzare input.  Basically describe what you actually want to get in the end (since you are dealing with an applied and not a theoretical question). Otherwise you can easily select 2 equal points of 50% and 50%.

Comment: I am looking for a way to convert the percentages I was provided into a format that =100%. I do not know of a way to convert the 100/90/50/15/5 breakdown into anything else which is why I did the math that I did with the arbitrary number of 200.

Comment: Trevor, you are not following me. Why do you need those percentages add up to 100%? What will the calculator calculate after such an input? I think you are confusing pmf (what your calculator expects) with a cdf (the data you have).

Comment: The calculator takes the percentages and the corresponding days as input. In the backend, the days are ran against their corresponding percentages (30 * .063 = 1.890, 180 * .283 = 50.94, etc.) and the results of each are added together to get an average number of days. From there, the average number of days can be ran against the number of hours of video coming in per day to get a total number of hours of video recorded for the whole retention policy (963.528 days in the aforementioned example, 963.528 * 200 = 192,706 total hours of video for the whole retention policy). Does that help?

Comment: Here is what you can feed to your calc: 1) 50% is kept for 365 days 2) 50% is kept for 365 days . Percentages add up to 100%.

Comment: What my calculator is coming up with is wrong and I know it is due to the percentages so I am not sure if I am right with the percentages I calculated or if my calculator is wrong (perhaps not handling the percentages correctly due to the percentages not descending as well as the days?)

Comment: What do you want to calculate eventually? Average number of days a video is kept? What is your final-final goal? What is the FULL data you have?